# Soundcloud avatar image larger than 100x100

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Is there a way, using the Soundcloud API, to get a user's image thats larger than 100x100? From what I've seen in [their docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) there arent any images larger than this: http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000011353294-n0axp1-large.jpg

Some sort of Javascript solution would be preferable.

Comment: Javascript front-end? Or back-end (Node.js), for retrieve json with front-end you can use Ajax. > Note: I retrive this http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/405726.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID and response return this header `access-control-allow-origin: *`, I believe that this works with front-end. Read about CORS.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yea, I meant JS front-end. I'm already using the API to get an image of the size in that link, I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to get a larger avatar image on the front-end.

Comment: I read the docs, but not found anything about retrieve "large images" from profile.
It may not be supported in current version of API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the url so that instead of 'large', it ends with 't500x500'